# Multiple nodes when connecting to the MQTT Server

Tags: erlang, mqtt

I have a server (A) using Erlang and it connects to an MQTT server (B) to listen to content from a topic.

It will handle the content received from that topic.

In the case of too many people in server B, when I deploy server A to multiple nodes (cluster) is it inadequate?

For example, when multiple servers listen to a topic, is it duplicated?

```erlang
init(_Args) ->
    {ok, C} = emqttc:start_link([{host, "127.0.0.1"},
                                 {client_id, <<"Node">>},
                                 {username, <<"Node">>},
                                 {password, <<"1">>},
                                 {reconnect, 3},
                                 {logger, {console, info}}]),

    %% The pending subscribe
    emqttc:subscribe(C, <<"Node/User">>, 1),
    {ok, #state{mqttc = C, seq = 1}}.
```

Comment: Every consumer that subscribes to a topic will reveive all messages on this topic. Do you want to consume every message exactly once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal circumstances every client subscribed to a given topic will receive all messages published on that topic.

As of MQTT v5<sup>*</sup> there is something called Shared Subscriptions, this allows a group of clients to all subscribe to a topic and messages will only be delivered to one of the group. This works by prefixing the topic with the `$share/<group-name>/`. So if the group name is `foo` and the topic is `Node/User` the Shared Subscription topic would be `$share/foo/Node/User`.

<sup>*</sup> Shared Subscriptions became part of the formal spec at MQTT v5, but some brokers had proprietary implementations before.